# I'm just a newcomer so I have troubles with this code

Tags: python-3.x

I don't know how to fix this problems and I am very confused why it has these errors:

[image]

Comment: `! pip install playsound`

Comment: Please do not post pictures of your code. Please cut and paste it into your question and, if possible, make is so other users can run your code to see the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

- To fix the first error, execute `pip install playsound` in the terminal.
- To fix the second error, import wikipedia after executing `pip install wikipedia` in the terminal like this:

```py
import wikipedia

# all of your other code

wikipedia.set_lang('vi')
language = 'vi'

# rest of your code
```

Comment: I think you may have to give us your entire code rather than a screenshot, so we can test it ourselves and give a working solution. Thanks!

Comment: sorry but code is very long i can' give it !

Comment: How did you import playsound & wikipedia?

Comment: and also are these the only errors you are facing?

Comment: i just type "import playsound" and "import wikipedia" and there are a lot of errors and i don't know how to fix thanks!